# React native project installation failed

Tags: javascript, java, android, react-native, gradle

```
`
android/app/src/main/java/com/weclean/executives/newarchitecture/components/MainComponentsRegistry.java:1: error: illegal character: '\u0000'

100 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
`
```

1. react-native file is not installing 'compileDebugJavaWithJavac' error was occurred,
2. how to solve this error - i tried ./gradlew clean, android studio - invalidate caches but not working
3. please give me solution to this problem

Comment: There is error in MainComponentsRegistry.java file.. Can you share that?

Comment: in MainComponenetsRegistry.java file only show NULL value